# How do QTextBlock or QTextFrame iterators work in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, iteration, qtextedit, qtextdocument

When working with a QTextDocument, Qt provides iterators (such as QTextBlock.iterator) to move through the contents. The documentation [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextblock-iterator.html) shows the C++ code, but obviously the `++` operator doesn't work and the PyQt version doesn't seem to have anything like a `next()` function.

So how do you make the iterator iterate?

The documentation for [QTextFrame.begin](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextframe.html) (which returns the iterator) has a broken link to "STL-style-Iterators", but I can't find any details of these being implemented in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextframe.html) shows that in PyQt, iterator objects support `__iadd__` and `__isub__`. This allows you to use, e.g. `it += 1` instead of `++it`.

Here's a small demo:

```
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit

app = QApplication(['test'])

edit = QTextEdit()
edit.setText('one<b>two</b>three<br>')

it = edit.document().firstBlock().begin()
while not it.atEnd():
    fragment = it.fragment()
    if fragment.isValid():
        print(fragment.text())
    it += 1
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: I don't know why, but following your example I'm only getting the first block. It looks like that the iterator is jumping at the end after the first block.

Comment: @toto The code in my question still works fine and produces exactly the same output. I obviously have no idea what you've done wrong in your own code, as I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
for i in range(10):
    textEdit.append("Paragraph %i" % i)
doc = textEdit.document()
for blockIndex in range(doc.blockCount()):
    block = doc.findBlockByNumber(blockIndex)
    print(block.text())
```

Sorry. I don't know about `QTextFrame`s. I tried adding the following, but apparently there were no frames to iterate. It didn't throw any errors though.

```
rootFrame = doc.rootFrame()
for frame in rootFrame.childFrames():
    cursor = frame.lastCursorPosition()
    print("I don't know what frames are for, but the cursor is at %i" % cursor.positionInBlock())
```